# How to draw a line in React JS with mouse events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I am trying to make a canvas web-app with Vite React (fairly new with React and JS in general). Currently I am using an onDrag event to draw a line in realtime (as the mouse moves), and it works except I do not want the element to be draggable. It is the only solution I have found that is able to track the mouse's location while having the mouse clicked.

As of now, it draws a circle on each location of the mouse while it is dragging. When I drag the second time it picks up the div as it should which is not my intention. I am looking for a more practical way to do this (probably some mouse event I am overlooking?).

The Div:

```
<div className="canvas" draggable onDrag={(handleOnDrag)}>
   {items.map((item) => (
   <div className="test" style={{
     left: item.x-5 + "px",
     top: item.y-5 + "px",
   }}
   ></div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Drag Function:

```
  function handleOnDrag(e){
    const {clientX, clientY} = e;
    setItems([...items, {x:clientX, y:clientY}])
  }
```

[image: Picture of Issue]

Comment: What about the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) native to browsers?

Comment: Follow-up on my comment above: MDN has a ["draw on canvas" example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event#examples) for the `mousedown` event, which may be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I’ll have a look, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mouse Events

Colloquially, pressing and moving the mouse can be considered "dragging".

But in web dev, "dragging" refers to the first part of "drag-and-drop" where you *drag an object.* Therefore, declaring your element as [`draggable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable) means you can drag *the element itself.*

Because there is no [event type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#event_listing) specifically for your usecase, you need to implement it yourself.

As the [**example on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event#examples) demonstrates, it can be implemented with the events `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup`. A simple flag for when the button is pressed to draw when moving works:

```js
// When true, moving the mouse draws on the canvas
let isDrawing = false;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

const myPics = document.getElementById('myPics');
const context = myPics.getContext('2d');

// event.offsetX, event.offsetY gives the (x,y) offset from the edge of the canvas.

// Add the event listeners for mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup
myPics.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  isDrawing = true;
});

myPics.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    drawLine(context, x, y, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;
  }
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    drawLine(context, x, y, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    isDrawing = false;
  }
});

function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 560px;
  height: 360px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Drawing with mouse events</h1>
<canvas id="myPics" width="560" height="360"></canvas>
```

## Drawing

Let's call "drawing" the manipulation of an actual image instead of a "lookalike" image.

That would mean that your code only gives off the illusion of drawing by mocking a "brush stroke" via *elements.* This also means that the longer we "draw", the more elements are added to our document:

```js
// Your React drawing app
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  
  const handleDrag = e => {
    const {clientX, clientY} = e;
    setItems([...items, {x:clientX, y:clientY}]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="canvas" draggable onDrag={handleDrag}>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div className="test"
          style={{ left: `${item.x-5}px`, top: `${item.y-5}px` }}></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render(<App></App>);

// Element counter
const elCount = document.getElementById("element-count");
let count = countElementsOf(document.documentElement);
function countElementsOf(node) {
  return 1 + Array.from(node.children)
    .reduce((count, n) =>
      count + countElementsOf(n), 0);
}

const options = { childList: true, subtree: true };
const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(m => {
    if (m.type !== "childList") return;
    count += m.addedNodes.length;
    count -= m.removedNodes.length;
    elCount.value = count;
  });
});
mutationObserver.observe(document.documentElement, options);
```

```css
/*Any styling for demonstration purposes*/
.canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 560px;
  height: 360px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!--React libraries-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<label for="element-count">
  HTML elements on this page: <input id="element-count" type=number value=0 readonly>
</label>

<div id="app"></div> <!--React app-->
```

As mentioned, the amount of elements on your page increases drastically while "drawing", which eventually impacts performance.

Also note that the individual dots (elements) are not connected, unlike a brush *stroke.*

We can solve the issues (increasing elements, disconnected "strokes") with the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), which is intended for drawing on the [`<canvas>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas).

Common ways to draw via the Canvas API are [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) or with its [path-like methods of the 2D-Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#paths). MDN's example uses the path-like approach, which I also personally recommend for beginners.

Refer to the copied snippet from MDN in the first section.

An additional benefit of using `<canvas>` is: Since it's effectively an image, you can actually copy or save it like any other image.